# Where do you put the database field names?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, oop

For example should I put the SQL field names in the class itself

```
public class Book {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "book";
    public static final String ID = "id";
    public static final String NUM_PAGES = "num_pages";

    private long id;
    private int numPages;

    public Book(long id, int numPages) {
        this.id = id;
        this.numPages = numPages;
    }

    //...

}
```

where

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //...

    public static final query = "select * from " + Book.TABLE_NAME; //for example

    //...

}
```

Or should the fields go inside the DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String BOOK_TABLE_NAME = "book";
    public static final String BOOK_ID = "id";
    public static final String BOOK_NUM_PAGES = "num_pages";

    //...

    public static final query = "select * from " + BOOK_TABLE_NAME; //for example

   //...

}
```

Mostly just trying to figure out where these names need to actually go for the sake of the CRUD functions.

Comment: I would not make constants to compose SQL strings. It almost is a do-it-yourself JPA or ORM, A total waste of time, as it adds fluff to the code base. Maybe collect the SQL pieces in separate XML or such, but with constants the risk of forgetting a comma remains just as problematic if not more. _Totally personal view_

Answer (score 0):

Both designs are valid, pick whichever you like better and run with it.

I personally try to model my POJOs so that the table column names correspond to the variable names but if that isn't possible I put the variables in the same POJO class so they're self-contained and very readable in other parts of the codebase.

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    public static final String TABLE = "books";

    public static final String PAGE_COUNT = "page_count";

    //everything else
}

@Service
public class SomeService {

    public void someMethod() {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Book.TABLE + " WHERE " + Book.PAGE_COUNT + " < 10";
    }
}
```